# Angular2: Catching 401 error for token refresh

Tags: typescript, angular, rxjs

I'm new to Angular2 and trying catch 401 error for token refresh with the plan to retry original request...

Here is my authService.refresh method:

```
refresh() : Observable<any> {
    console.log("refreshing token");
    this.accessToken = null;
    let params : string = 'refresh_token=' + this.refreshToken + '&grant_type=refresh_token';
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + this.clientCredentials);
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    return Observable.create(
        observer => {
            this._http.post('http://localhost:8080/oauth/token', params, {
                    headers : headers
            })
            .map(res => res.json()).subscribe(
                (data) => {
                    this.accessToken = data.access_token;
                    observer.next(this.accessToken);
                    observer.complete();
                },
                (error) => {
                    Observable.throw(error);
                }
            );
        });
 }
```

and then I try to use refresh functionality in my component method:

```
update(index : number) {
 let headers = new Headers();
 headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this._authService.accessToken);
 this._http.get('http://localhost:8080/rest/resource', {
    headers : headers
 })
 .catch(initialError =>{
    if (initialError && initialError.status === 401) {
       this._authService.refresh().flatMap((data) => {
         if ( this._authService.accessToken != null) {
             // retry with new token
             headers = new Headers();
             headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' +  this._authService.accessToken);
             return this._http.get('http://localhost:8080/rest/resource', { headers : headers });
         } else {
         return Observable.throw(initialError);
         }
       });
    } else {
      return Observable.throw(initialError);
    }
 })
 .map(res => res.json())
 .subscribe(
    data => {
      this.resources[index] = data;
    },
    error => {
      console.log("error="+JSON.stringify(error));
    }
 ); 
}
```

This doesn't work for some reason...
I wonder what is the correct implementation of token refresh functionality in angular2?`enter code here`

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the Günter's answer, I would leverage the `accessToken` from the `flatMap` callback parameter instead of using a service property:

```
if (initialError && initialError.status === 401) {
   this._authService.refresh().flatMap((accessToken) => {
     // retry with new token
     headers = new Headers();
     headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' +  accessToken);
     return this._http.get('http://localhost:8080/rest/resource', { 
       headers : headers });
   });
} else {
  return Observable.throw(initialError);
}
```

This article could interest you (section "Handling security"):

- http://restlet.com/blog/2016/04/18/interacting-efficiently-with-a-restful-service-with-angular2-and-rxjs-part-3/

Comment: What about multiple concurrent 401s when token has expired.

It would seem that your solution would call multiple times to refresh(), first succeeding and the rest failing.

Maybe sharing the initial refresh promise for rest of the requests might solve this.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to use `Observable.create(`

```
        return this._http.post('http://localhost:8080/oauth/token', params, {
                headers : headers
        })
        .map(res => res.json())
        .map(data => {
                this.accessToken = data.access_token;
                observer.next(this.accessToken);
                observer.complete();
            },
        ).catch(error) => Observable.throw(error));
```

just don't call `.subscribe()` (which will return a `Subscription` instead of an `Observable`, instead use `.map(...)` and `.catch(...)`

Comment: Sorry for the DV, my bad, thought you were talking about the second part of the OP's code.

Comment: No prob. Thanks for the comment.